# ASP.NET Login Not Reading Connection String

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web-config, login-control

This is probably a noob question, I am new to ASP.NET Login controls. The problem is, the login page loads and you enter the username and password. However, it always says "Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again." That prompted me to see if it was even hitting the db. It is not, because this is the connection string as you can see below:

```
connectionString="Data2121212 Source=20e2127213597;Initial Catalog=ramsl323312sanddb;User Id=ramsl1342anddb42o;Password=r13zzzzzzbs;"
```

Even with that connection string which is completely invalid it throws no error. So obviously its not even trying to connect. What I can't figure out, is why is not connecting. I was told that the login control would just read the web.config file and pick up the connection string etc. But its not. Can someone please explain to me whats going on?

And yes, the site is using that config file.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
        <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data2121212 Source=20e2127213597;Initial Catalog=ramsl323312sanddb;User Id=ramsl1342anddb42o;Password=r134zAP5bs;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>

        <authentication mode="Forms">

            <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"/>



    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>

    <!-- Validation and decryption keys must exactly match and cannot
         be set to "AutoGenerate". The validation and decryption
         algorithms must also be the same. -->
    <machineKey validationKey="AB5D0FE7450DA6CB8821D213C36EE85BC26FB34259E194B86F2D7240D10B42AE8887A5204B733EF7E860963C0403CA12FBF0892AD50570B4E79D5DC530FD1CFF" decryptionKey="1ED07D110F095B571EB62B0EF4C6D6F4F2DA5596103C233E98C8B6832C23F888" validation="AES" decryption="AES" />
        <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"> 
            <providers>
                <clear/> 
                <add connectionStringName="LocalSQLServer" applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" passwordFormat="Encrypted" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add connectionStringName="LocalSQLServer" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"/>
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add connectionStringName="LocalSQLServer" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>




  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>




</configuration>
```

Comment: How you read it? Because you have 3 same connectionString name. System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSQLServer"].ConnectionString;

Comment: @kad1r Thats just specifying the connection to the db, for each provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! My noob client coded the login control all wrong apparently, because when I used a new one, it worked great!

Also, great tips here for anyone who has an issue like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27682/Your-Login-Attempt-was-not-Successful-Please-Try

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following line in:

So your new connection strings settings should look like this:

```
 <connectionStrings>
   <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
  <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data2121212 Source=20e2127213597;Initial Catalog=ramsl323312sanddb;User Id=ramsl1342anddb42o;Password=r13zzzzzzbs;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

now for as long as your Database has the ASP.Net database in it with a user account it should work perfectly fine.

Comment: And yeah it does have that. I used the aspnet_regsql tool. Its got it. Funny thing is, ASP.NET Configuration Tool can see it just fine, and add roles etc.